# Storing iteration results of a function and using them when called by another function

Tags: c++, loops

I have three functions, for example:

```
void firstFunc(entry) {
     this function returns list of entries that are stored in an array
}

void secondFunc() {
    while (loop x number of times) {
        firstFunc(the value here gets updated with the next entry every loop);
        compare the updated entry with another local parameter that is set within this method;
        if lesser { do something; }
    }     
}

void thirdFunc() {
    while (loop x number of times) {
        firstFunc(the value here gets updated with the next entry every loop);
        compare the updated entry with another local parameter that is set within this method;
        if greater { do something; }
    }     
}
```

Here, "firstFunc" is looped twice (once in "secondFunc" and then in "thirdFunc"). All I want is something like this:

```
void firstFunc(entry) {
     this function returns list of entries that are stored in an array
}

while (loop x number of times) {
        firstFunc(the value here gets updated with the next entry every loop);
}

void secondFunc() {
    while (loop x number of times) {
        use the value next updated value from firstFunc;
        compare the updated entry with another local parameter that is set within this method;
        if lesser { do something; }
    }     
}

void thirdFunc() {
    while (loop x number of times) {
        use the value next updated value from firstFunc;
        compare the updated entry with another local parameter that is set within this method;
        if greater { do something; }
    }     
}
```

In the above code, the looping of firstFunc is done once instead of doing it in secondFunc and thirdFunc. My question is how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean to store the results of `firstFunc` so that, given the same arguments later, it just reuses the results from last time?

Comment: Above, values are getting iterated in "secondFunc" and then again from the beginning in "thirdFunc". This is taking too much time. I just don't want to iterate it again from the beginning in "thirdFunc".

Comment: the value of b in secondFunc and thirdFunc never changes...so what are asking again?

Comment: My mistake on the first write-up. I just edited firstFunc(), secondFunc and thirdFunc. So in each iteration in secondFunc and thirdFunc, we will be having the next value in array b which is getting compared with s1 and s2.

Comment: Can you post some actual code so we don't get confused about what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: The actual code would confuse even more since it has a lot of unrelated parameters

Comment: At least make this complete and working code. I am pretty sure no one understand what you are trying to do. I want to say yes to your answer, but can't because I don't know what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Code changed for better readability. Expected outcome is also added.

Comment: No, I think the actual code would have made more sense.  When we see code, we can attempt to infer your intentions.  When you don't understand code, and then you try to describe it in non-code, it becomes more confusing.

Comment: You can use a static array variable so you don't have to pass the same one over and over again if several functions will be using it, even if just one function updates its values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to memoize the results of each firstFunc().

```
memoArr = []
while (loop x number of times) {
    memoArr[x] = firstFunc(the value here gets updated with the next entry every loop);
}
```

On second and third functions use the value from the array instead of calling the function again.